# What statically typed languages are similar to Python?

Tags: python, programming-languages

Python is the nicest language I currently know of, but static typing is a big advantage due to auto-completion (although there is limited support for dynamic languages, it is nothing compared to that supported in static). I'm curious if there are any languages which try to add the benefits of Python to a statically typed language. In particular I'm interesting in languages with features like:

- Syntax support: such as that for dictionaries, array comprehensions
- Functions: Keyword arguments, closures, tuple/multiple return values
- Runtime modification/creation of classes
- Avoidance of specifying classes everywhere (in Python this is due to duck typing, although type inference would work better in a statically typed language)
- Metaprogramming support: This is achieved in Python through reflection, annotations and metaclasses

Are there any statically typed languages with a significant number of these features?

Comment: This "Runtime modification/creation of classes" is pretty much as anti-"static typing" as you can get. There are other ways to solve a problem in statically-typed programs.

Comment: Autocompletion is a tool feature, not a language feature.  Some IDE's (e.g., Komodo) can do autocompletion for Python.  As long as you avoid tricky meta-programming.

Comment: @viraptor:  I could add "avoidance of specifying classes everywhere" to that.  Classes are types in most class systems, and not having to specify a type is a bit odd for a statically typed language.

Comment: @viraptor - I understand the difficulties in many static languages, but it isn't a complete road block. @Lott - static typing seems to always lead to better autocompletion @David: Type inference avoids the necessity of always specifying classes

Comment: @David Thornley: Actually I like Haskell where you can drop most of the type declarations and still be completely static. It might be different, but why odd?...

Comment: @viraptor:  I'm trying to learn Haskell right now, and it looks odd to me.  Quite possibly I'd comment differently a few months from now.

Comment: Have you compared C++ 23 and Python?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[Boo](https://github.com/bamboo/boo/wiki) is a statically typed language for the Common Language Infrastructure (aka. the Microsoft .NET platform). The syntax is *highly* inspired by Python, and hashes/lists/array are part of the syntax:

```
i = 5
if i > 5:
    print "i is greater than 5."
else:
    print "i is less than or equal to 5."

hash = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'monkey': 3, 42: 'the answer'}
print hash['a']
print hash[42]

for item in hash:
    print item.Key, '=>', item.Value
```

Comment: Boo is really nice. Syntactic support is as good or better than Python. Function support is first class. Type inference and duck typing are available. There are closures and macros provide for a form of meta programming. Classes in general can't be modified at runtime, but with some of the features this is less of an issue

Comment: Are there any bechmark comparisons for execution speed of Boo vs. Python?

Comment: This is just a guess, but I am assuming that the execution speed of Boo would be roughly similar to that of C#, in which case the performance would probably be substantially greater than Python: http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u32/benchmark.php?test=all&lang=python3&lang2=csharp&data=u32

Comment: IIRC, Boo is not supported anymore

Answer (score 15):

[Cobra](http://cobra-language.com/) is a statically typed language for the CLR (as Boo). From its web page:

> Cobra is a general purpose programming
>   language with:
>
> ```
>  - a clean, high-level syntax
>  - static and dynamic binding
>  - first class support for unit tests and contracts
>  - compiled performance with scripting conveniences
>  - lambdas and closures
>  - extensions and mixins
>  - ...and more
> ```

```
Sample code:

"""
This is a doc string for the whole module.
"""


class Person
    """
    This is a class declaration.
    """

    var _name as String  # declare an object variable. every instance of Person will have a name
    var _age as int

    cue init(name as String, age as int)
        _name = name
        _age = age

    def sayHello
        # This is a method

        # In strings, anything in brackets ([]) is evaluated as an expression,
        # converted to a string and substituted into the string:
        print 'Hello. My name is [_name] and I am [_age].'

    def add(i as int, j as int) as int
        """ Adds the two arguments and returns their sum. """
        return i + j
```

Answer (score 11):

Although it is not object-oriented, [**Haskell**](http://www.haskell.org/) offers a significant number of the features that interest you:

- Syntax support for list comprehensions, plus `do` notation for a wide variety of sequencing/binding constructs.  (Syntax support for dictionaries is limited to lists of pairs, e.g,

  ```
  dict = ofElements [("Sputnik", 1957), ("Apollo", 1969), ("Challenger", 1988)]
  ```
- Functions support full  closures and multiple return values using tuple types.  Keyword arguments are not supported but a powerful feature of "implicit arguments" can sometimes substitute.
- No runtime modification of classes, types or objects.
- Avoidance of specificying classes/types everywhere through *type inference*.
- Metaprogramming using Template Haskell.

Also, just so you will feel at home, Haskell has significant indentation!

I actually think Haskell has quite a different feel from Python overall, but that is primarily because of the extremely powerful static type system.   If you are interested in trying a statically typed language, Haskell is one of the most ambitious ones out there right now.

Answer (score 8):

It may not match all your needs, but have a look at [Boo - The wristfriendly language for the CLI](http://boo.codehaus.org/)

If you do, I highly recommend [DSLs in Boo: Domain-Specific Languages in .NET](http://www.manning.com/rahien/) which apart from the DSL aspects, covers Boo syntax in a very nice appendix and a lot of meta-programming.

Furthermore the [tutorials](http://boo.codehaus.org/Tutorials) are a great resource.

Answer (score 5):

The Go programming language. I've seen some similar paradigm.

Comment: Go does have some nice syntactical constructs, but as far as I know it doesn't have many of the other features

Answer (score 4):

Rpython is a subset of Python that is statically typed.

Comment: No standard libraries, only intended for use in creating interpreters.

Answer (score 2):

The D programming language is a statically typed, natively compiled language that has some significant features inspired by Python.

Arrays and associative arrays are built into the language.  There are no list comprehensions, but the std.range and std.algorithm libraries fill much of that void.  For example, here's a way to sum up all the even numbers from 0 to 100 in D:

```
auto result = reduce!"a + b"(
    filter!"a % 2 == 0"(
        iota(0, 100)
    )
);
```

There are no keyword arguments so far, but closures are there.  Tuples are supported, but not unpacked automatically.

In D, you avoid specifying classes (and types in general) everywhere with the `auto` keyword and with templates.  For example, here is generic code to find the product of  array of any numeric type:

```
// The return type of product() is inferred.
auto product(T)(T[] array) {
    T ret = 1;
    foreach(num; array) { // typeof(num) is inferred.
        ret *= num;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

D's metaprogramming support consists of compile time introspection (for example, you can iterate over the fields of a class or struct at compile time), runtime type information, and templates that are actually designed for metaprogramming beyond simple generics.  For example, here's how to write a generic function that generates a default comparison operation for two structs, which is useful if you need an arbitrary total ordering for something like a binary tree:

```
/**Returns -1 if lhs < rhs, 0 if lhs == rhs, 1 if lhs > rhs.*/
int compareStructs(T)(T lhs, T rhs) {
    foreach(tupleIndex, value; lhs.tupleof) {
        if(value < rhs.tupeof[tupleIndex]) {
            return -1;
        } else if(value > rhs.tupleof[tupleIndex]) {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Lobster (http://strlen.com/lobster/) is a statically typed programming language with Python-esque syntax.

It has a few things you're asking for:

- Type inference, so your code can look similar to Python without having to specify types everywhere. In fact, it goes further with type inference than languages like Haskell.
- Closures: they are syntactically lighter than Python (create your own control structures) and yet more powerful (may be multi-line, you can return from them to enclosing functions).
- Multiple return values.

It doesn't do so well on these items:

- Syntax for dictionaries or array comprehensions. Though its syntax for map/filter is so minimal that it can probably compete with array comprehensions.
- Keyworded arguments currently only for constructors.
- Runtime modification of classes: nope.. its a pretty static language.
- Reflection: also nope, though this would certainly be possible.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but I think it's worth mentioning Nim, that has reached version 1.0 recently and one of its best characteristics is it's metaprogramming capabilities.
And a lot more.

https://nim-lang.org/

Answer (score 1):

Autocompletion is still possible in a dynamically typed language; nothing prevents the IDE from doing type inference or inspection, even if the language implementation doesn't.

Comment: Exactly. Tools like PyDev are nice but the autocomplete/intellisense is awful. When it works it's far too slow.

Comment: The autocompletion needed for dynamic languages is nothing compared to static.

Comment: Autocompletion is impossible _in general_ in dynamically-typed languages.  And it's undesirable, too.  The whole advantage of dynamic typing is that it is often convenient to write code that cannot be type-checked.  If you're going to write a program that *can* be type-checked automatically, you might as well use static typing.  Hence this question.

Answer (score 1):

If auto-completion is the thing you are looking for, then you might wanna stick with Python and use a great IDE instead.

Try PyCharm: http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/index.html

Unless you are coding some extremely dynamic stuff (which you can't probably do in a static language anyway), it will keep up with the code and give you completion, refactoring and all the other goodies we are used to in statically typed languages.

You can give typehints to the IDE where you really need it by doing:

```
def foo(bar):
    if 0: bar = Bar() # "if 0" will be removed from the bytecode automatically by python
    bar. # will now autocomplete
```

Comment: Anyone know how PyCharm compares to Eclipse Python support? I'll look at it, but I'll still be surprised if it is even close to statically typed languages

Comment: I find it way better than PyDev atleast. But, I switched to PyCharm about a year ago, so my opinions of PyDev is a bit outdated.

Comment: How does if 0 provide a type hint?

Comment: The typehint is "bar = Bar()", the "if 0" is to make python not use that line (since we want bar to be the value passed in). When using "if 0" python will remove that line completely from the bytecode and there will be no performance penalty at all.

Comment: The fact that you have to go through this hackery shows how Python's IDEs could be improved

Comment: @prestomation: And how would that be? If I write a function, how on earth should the IDE know what type the arguments are? Not until I have actually begun using the function elsewhere in my code can it make an educated guess. Until then some kind of type hint is needed.

Comment: @truppo: That's kind of the point of this whole question. With static typing the IDE *would* know. So you're never going to get a python IDE that has code completion as good as something like Java or Intellisense.

Comment: It could just display all known methods of all objects, kind of ugly but what you want would always be in the auto complete list!

Comment: You can also add type information in the docstring or, if using python3, as an annotation.  No hackery required.  PyCharm will do introspection on both and will give you the right type info.

Answer (score 0):

I think Eric and PyScripter have nice autocompletion on Windows, but maybe not as good as PyTools for Visual Studio (Express).

For static typing in Python, i'd use Cython: http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/cythonize.html